# minimal combination of key value relations

Tags: java

I got an two dimensional array like this

```
x = new ArrayList<String>();
y = new ArrayList<String>();

[put data in x/y]

// generate field
this.grid = new boolean[x.size()][y.size()];
for (String xId: x) {
    for (String yId: y) {
        this.grid[x.indexOf(xId)][y.indexOf(yId)] = false;
    }
}

// parse to field
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> element : this.relations.entrySet()) {
    int xId = x.indexOf(element.getKey());
    for (String selector: element.getValue()) {
        int yId = y.indexOf(selector);
        this.grid[xId][yId] = true;
    }
}
```

result

```
     y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9
    ___________________________ 
x1 |  -  -  -  X  -  X  X  -  - 
x2 |  X  -  X  -  -  -  -  X  -
x3 |  X  -  X  -  -  -  -  -  X 
x4 |  -  -  X  -  -  -  -  -  -
x5 |  -  X  -  X  X  X  X  -  -
x6 |  X  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  X
x7 |  -  -  -  X  -  X  X  -  -
x8 |  -  -  X  -  -  -  -  -  -
x9 |  X  X  -  -  X  -  -  -  X
```

the result basically gives this information:

```
x1 => [y4, y6, y7]
x2 => [y1, y3, y8]
x3 => [y1, y3, y9]
x4 => [y3]
...
```

respectively this:

```
y1 => [x2, x3, x6, x9]
y2 => [x5,x9]
...
```

so with this input:

```
x1 => [y4, y6, y7]
x2 => [y1, y3, y8]
x3 => [y1, y3, y9]
```

the result should look like this:

```
[x1]     => [y4, y6, y7]
[x2, x3] => [y1, y3]
[x2]     => [y8]
[x3]     => [y9]
```

i call it the minimal combination.. ;)

any ideas? thoughts? hints? ^^

after a view hours diggin the web i think that the problem area is called "formal concept analysis"

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to translate the input into the output?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes.. atm i speculating about the best way to do it.. i think i have to group the matchings of each row and compare them to the matchings of the other rows.. atm i got more then 500^400 combinations.. i dont know if there is an algorithm to solve this 100%.. maybe there is only a way to approximate the result with N iterations or something like this.. thats the reason for my question..

Comment: I don't know about an algorithm to solve it, but if it were me I'd add the two rows I was comparing into a `Set`, then use the `.retainAll()` to remove the stuff that's not common to both.  You would have to do it for all rows against all rows, and it seems like this would grow exponentially with each row/column you added.